# How to insert a row into another table during an on conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I want to insert in a ManyToMany relationship (between 'fiche' and quality) a line (same principle as a log) when an insertion fails because the key is duplicated.

example:

```
insert into fiche (content) values ('toto')
 on conflict  (content) do
insert into fiche_qualites (poi_id, qualites_id) values (idPoi, 'Code error');
```

My error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "insert"
```

I'm in a loop doing mass inserts and I want to be able to keep track when I have a duplicate (detected by uniqueness).

Comment: You better using a trigger. I don't think postgresql supports insert for `on conlfict` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: @JorgeCampos it is possible to though to make a CTE that returns the `xmax` of the inserted record. If it returns 0, it means the the record is new :)

Comment: Indeed the trigger can meet my needs but since it is a mass update and a rather long script.sql (in terms of lines) the with seems more maintainable to me and it also meets my needs . thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a PL/pgSQL block to catch an `unique_violation` [exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) and handle it.

```sql
do $$
begin
  insert into fiche (content) values ('toto');
exception 
  when unique_violation then
    insert into fiche_qualites (poi_id, qualites_id) values (idPoi, 'Code error');
end;
$$;
```

The block may be shaped as a reusable function too.

```sql
create or replace function insert_or_log(arg_content text)
returns void language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  insert into fiche (content) values (arg_content);
exception 
  when unique_violation then
    insert into fiche_qualites (poi_id, qualites_id)
    values ((select idPoi from fiche where content = arg_content), 'Code error');
end;
$$;
```

Comment: How to reuse the blog?

Comment: Answer updated with a function. A scalar subquery added to extract `idPoi` of the conflicting `fiche` record.

Answer (score 3):

[`Triggers`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/) are the most intuitive / flexible approach, but since your use case is only about keeping track of the duplicated entries in a separated table you can use a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/) (aka WITH clause) returning the [`xmax`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-system-columns.html) of the new records - new records always have a `xmax` = 0. Then finally in the outer query you filter only the inserted records to store in the "duplicates" table, e.g.

```
WITH j AS (
  INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'foo')
  ON CONFLICT (id) 
  DO UPDATE SET txt = EXCLUDED.txt
  RETURNING xmax=0 AS inserted,*
)
INSERT INTO t_duplicates 
SELECT id,txt FROM j 
WHERE NOT inserted -- see boolean expression in the RETURNING clause
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/FFZe7YW8)

Comment: on the other hand if I add a second time (1, 'foo') I have an error:ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.

Comment: @Camel4488 from your question I didn't understand that you have multiple inserts in a single statement. I thought it was only a single record per insert. But you're right, if it is the case, PL/pgSQL is the way to go to solve it (triggers, functions, anonymous code blocks, etc ..) cheers!

Comment: Sorry if I misspoke, I'm using a translator. Indeed I can have 2 or more hints for violation. thank you